# Is it possible to find the index of an input inside a form field?

Tags: jquery, css, html, zurb-foundation

How can I determine the index of an `<input>` element inside the form...

Why do I want to do this?

It'll help me give error codes in the backend and using the error code, I can use JQuery to automatically update the error message beneath the form `<input>` field using `<small>` tag (used for errors in zurb-foundation) and make same code scalable to all pages.

Obviously, I'll design error codes in the backend according to the place value in question...

Comment: it's an idea in my head unf.

Comment: can't you just use the 'id' or name? if you send some input to your backend you know where it comes from. (and that's why you need to add some code -> this is the easy option, either you haven't thought of that and have an XY problem here, or you have, but you can't use it for some reason you know but we don't)

Comment: I initially didn't want to do it because I thought it was gruntwork (checking manually for all ids by name). 

Now after seeing the first answer, I realize even that can be automated, so that's going to be my next attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `selector1.index(selector2)`, e.g.

```
$('#myform input').index($('#myinput'))
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7K22B/

API doc: http://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: That's a beauty! Thanks a lot.